# Deregister scripts on unnecessary pages in WP

Tags: wordpress

I have installed WP Pokks plugin. I using in on some of pages and need to deregister its styles and scripts on other pages.

I found some code in plugin which registers scripts:

```
### Function: Enqueue Polls JavaScripts/CSS
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'poll_scripts');
    function poll_scripts() {
        // code
    }
```

So for deregistering its scripts i am using next code in my `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'deregister_polls_scripts_and_styles' );

function deregister_polls_scripts_and_styles() {
    if ( is_home() ) {
        remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'poll_scripts');
    }
}
```

So it must deregister polls scripts on homepage, but id does not. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: You can try like `<?php wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); ?>`

Comment: I am using another plugin and same solution and all works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'de_script', 100 );

function de_script() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

Comment: But why same solution working for another plugin? And when i am using it without add_action it works.

Comment: Hm, it is works but why remove_action does not? It may be many scripts in plugin, so i need to remove all of them. Write many code.

Comment: If you are using `remove_action` then it will remove all added scripts,so its better to use `wp_dequeue_script` OR `wp_deregister_script` for specific script file.

Comment: I need remove all scriptsof plugin on some pages. But it does not working... Waiting for help...